# Getting sick while working out

Tags: workout-routines, injury-prevention

Healthy 41 year old, I've been working out regular for about 2 years now. 6' 193 lbs.

When I work out I sometimes get sick.
Worst case I get cold sweat, nausea, weakness, need to go to the bathroom.

I sit down for 10 min, drink some water and it's gone.

Usually happens when I do cardio / HITT but sometimes it happens after weight training. One time it happened after going in the sauna after a regular workout where I was feeling fine.

I'm a normal guy, not doing anything extreme and I feel I can squeeze an bit extra at the end - maybe 1-2 mile run on the treadmill or some crunches...

Any ideas how to manage this?

Comment: How much do you eat and sleep? It might not be enough is my first thought. Also do you get dizzy? Dizziness can indicate low blood sugar or low blood pressure which are both related and something I’ve ran into with cold sweats while working out forcing me to sit down

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain, there may be multiple things that could cause your symptoms, but one common cause that affects you during exercise and expresses these symptoms is low sodium.
I experienced these same things at one time and after some lengthy research and beleived it to be low sodium.

If this is the case all you need is to drink isotonic drinks. When you sweat a lot you lose salt through your sweat. You then drink a lot of pure water thus diluting the salt in your body. Common symptoms being nausea, light-headedness, low energy. This is easily counteracted by either buying isotonic sports drinks, or as I do, make your own. To make my own a fill a 700ml bottle, add 25-30g of sugar and a quater-tsp of salt.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before this could be many things, but I'd focus on being properly hydrated throughout the day. How much water do you drink *per day*?

Unless you're training for several hours, you don't really need an isotonic drink during your activity as long as you're properly hydrated. A good starting point is 1 liter of water per 20kg of body weight (it sounds like a lot, but it's alright if you do regular exercise).

Avoid eating large meals close to heavy training (training at least 1h after a big meal, small meals could be 30 min). Properly salt your food. Do some blood tests, look for vitamin deficiencies. Check if you need to supplement with D3, Zinc, Magnesium. Get some potassium (eat bananas for example). Have some creatine. Check your blood pressure (it sounds like you could have low blood pressure; mine is a bit low and increasing salt in my meals and water intake seemed to get me better). All these should help.